# ionic 2 ion-inputs inside list

Tags: list, input, ionic2

I am trying to make a custom item containing 3 inputs in a list in ionic 2, but it's not working. When I put only 1 input, there's no problem. But if I put other tag with "

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let pergunta of avaliacao; let i=index">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-input placeholder="Pergunta" [(ngModel)]="pergunta.descricao" clearInput></ion-input>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="pergunta.opcoes"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-label>Obrigatória</ion-label><ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="pergunta.obrigatoria"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-row> 
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: Nop. Didn't work. I think it's not a script problem, but a html issue. The inputs simply don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. It seems I can't put several input inside ion-item. Just replaced ion-item for div