# Ionic 2 Ion-Input (Video Example)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, html-input

I am building an ionic 2 app and I am currently working on creating a table. This table is being built by :

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-80>
                {{ ingredient.name}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col width-20>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.id"></ion-input>
           </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

This is just a snippet and in reality, this part is actually inside an *ngFor. The problem comes as the whole row becomes non-rendered. When I look in Chrome dev tools, it doesn't show the row. As soon as I take it out of the ion-row, it will show correctly. Even replacing ion-row and ion-col for divs with styled widths and floats...the same issue occurs.

Here is a similar question : [ionic 2 ion-inputs inside list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39055152/4470939) but the solution is not feasible for me as I need to use ion-option-buttons which means I cannot replace ion-item with a div. Lastly, a workaround is to just use a regular input and although this works stylistically, it does not perform well when I build the project on the phone. I'm fact, when clicking into ion-input, the keyboard opens nicely and closes nicely. But with a regular input, it causes my screen to jump partially on open...and very noticeably on close and is why I need ion-input. I actually had regular inputs to begin with and then found this jumping issue and am now trying to solve this ion-input problem.

Does anybody have any suggestions or ideas on how to solve this? I really appreciate any assistance.

-- **EDIT**

Here is a link to a video demonstrating the issue:
https://youtu.be/C0_yeK2sGG8

Comment: Where you want to put your ion-option-buttons?

Comment: I would like to slide them from the side. So the regular ion-item will be showing, but then on a swipe, will be able to see these options.